# How to select a block with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the height of a list of blocks from Puppeteer but I can't select my block in `page.evaluate()` as it throws an error.

So, I have this code:

```
(async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

        for (let property in blockIds) {
            if (blockIds.hasOwnProperty(property)) { console.log(property);
                const height = await page.evaluate(property, () => {
                    return document.getElementById(property).offsetHeight;
                });
                console.log(property, height)
            }
        }

        await browser.close();
    })();
```

- `html` is a valid HTML page in string.
- `blockIds` is an object of this type: `{ 'block-id': null, 'block-id-2': null}`

My idea was to get the height of all my blocks so I could have this output:
`{'block-id': 123, 'block-id-2': 321}`

But when I run this code, I got the following output
(Note that *question-2* is my blockId)

> question-2
>
> (node:6338) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: question is not defined
>       at :1:1
>
> (node:6338) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I really don't understand why this code is not working as, if I put directly «question-2» inside the `document.getElementById`, Puppeteer returns me the correct height.

So, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The function should be passed as `page.evaluate`'s first argument as indicated in Puppeteer's documentation.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

2. Any arguments passed to `page.evaluate` must also be passed to the function you are passing. `page.evaluate((arg)=>{}, arg);`
3. With a `for...in` loop the value is not assigned to `property`, it is assigning the property name. To access the value within a `for...in` loop you should do the following: `blockIds[property]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Putting it all together you get:

```
await page.evaluate((property) => {
    return document.getElementById(property)_.offsetHeight;
}, blockIds[property])
```

You may want to consider switching from a `for...in` loop to a `for...of` loop. This will assign the value to `property` allowing you a more concise loop body as it also ignores properties inherited from the prototype, so you can omit the `.hasOwnProperty` check as it won't be needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

That would result in:

```
for (let property of blockIds) {
    //no need to check for .hasOwnProperty here
    const height = await page.evaluate((property) => {
        return document.getElementById(property).offsetHeight;
    }, property); //no need to use blockIds[property] here
}
```